# How to find contents in the middle with sed?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I would like to find words with this pattern u'sometext', the desired output would be sometext only, e.g.:

```
u'amy', u'1', u'bob', u'2',
```

This becomes:

```
amy 1 bob 2
```

I tried `sed -e 's/u'\''\(^*\)'\'',/\1/g' file.txt` but it doesn't work. Can i ask where i got wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not *entirely* certain what you were hoping to capture with the `^*` pattern, that looks to me to be zero or more occurrences of the start text anchor.

You can used the `sed` command in the following transcript to achieve your desired results:

```
pax$ echo "u'amy', u'1', u'bob', u'2'," | sed -e "s/u'\([^']*\)',/\1/g"
amy 1 bob 2
```

The `[^']*` inside the capture parentheses will basically capture everything after the `'` to just before the next `'`. You'll also notice I've switched to using the double-quote `"` to surround the `sed` command. That simplifies the escaping you need to do within the string if it uses single quotes.

It also changes what the shell is likely to do to your string but, in this case, you're not using anything that the shell would interpret.

---

You could also avoid captures if you opt to remove just the stuff you don't want, rather than replacing the stuff you don't want *and* the stuff you do want, with the stuff you do want<sup>(a)</sup>. That would go something like:

```
pax$ echo "u'amy', u'1', u'bob', u'2'," | sed -e "s/u'//g" -e "s/', */ /g"
amy 1 bob 2
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Possibly my most *torturous* use of the *"Lingua Anglais"* that I've inflicted for several decades - I should probably be imprisoned for crimes against English :-)

Comment: I'm quite new to regex and didn't understand it very well:( Thank you so much for your explanation, that really helps a lot!!

Comment: @XiaohanPeng: glad I could help. Re learning regexes, don't worry, you'll get there. It's just like learning `vim`. Why, some people become adept at it in as little as as three decades :-)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/u'\''\([^'\'']*\)'\'',\?/\1/g' file
```

This answer is for completeness as the accepted answer is perfectly adequate.

When surrounding sed commands by single quotes `'`'s, if the command contains a single quote a hole must be punched through to the underlying shell, i.e. close off the existing command `'`, insert a single quote from the shell `\'` and then open up the remaining commands `'`.

Sometimes by surrounding the sed commands by double quotes (which also allows the shell to interpolate variables for instance) unexpected results are obtained e.g. `<<<'!' sed "s/!/X/"` where bash history expansion is invoked. The solution I have found is always to surround sed commands by single quotes and these kind of problems do not appear (at the expense of the long winded single quote quoting!).